# Creating a Shopify app which creates a contact form with shortcode and sends the values to the app backend

Tags: shopify, contact-form, shopify-app, zendesk

Currently I’m trying to create a Shopify app which will be used to get input values from a contact form and use those values in an API request to Zendesk.

I already created the API request for Zendesk and made sure it works. Now I need to get the values from the contact form on the frontend to the Shopify app. I know of several apps which you can use to create a contact form and then use a shortcode to place that form on a page in Shopify.
I was wondering how I could recreate something like that. And then how I could send the values from the contact form to my Shopify app.

Can someone tell me how I can create this?

Thanks in advance,
Ivan

Answer (score 0):

If you have an App, just add a Proxy endpoint to it, and then your App can use a front-end call to your proxy with the result of the form input. That can then be used to securely inform your App of the input, and you can go from there. It is what the Proxy does best.

Comment: Okey, so make a Proxy endpoint and call this on the frontend? So is this basically like an API call? Sorry not really familiar with proxy.

Comment: It is more like a standard XHR call. You GET or POST to /a/endpoint or /tools/endpoint and if you expect JSON back, you'll get it!

Comment: Hi, is it also possible to send a file with this request? I'm using Shopify so I can't upload the file in advance, I need to send it with the request from the HTML form so that I can upload it with the Zendesk API with my own app.

Comment: File uploads can be done at the product level with line item properties.

Comment: Any way you could show me how or maybe point me in the right direction?

Comment: Look up Line Item Properties with shopify in their developer tutorials for theme customizations. All is there.